# Android mediarecorder produces video with green lines on low res devices

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I tried to record video using 2 methods on a low res device:

**FIRST WAY**

I used mediacodec class provided by android, and the recorded video was good no matter what size I create the video with.

**SECOND WAY**

I used media recorder class, which should be better and more stable. But when I specify different video sizes when creating with media recorder I get videos with green lines.

After research I discovered that it has to do with video size.

when I use these sizes on media recorder: 320x240 or 480x270 or 1280x270 .... I get a weird green lined video. But when I use square dimensions 200x200 or 500x500 .... I get no green lines even though the video looks elongated.

**My quesion:**

How do we avoid this?

How to control this?

Why it happens only when recording with media recorder and not media codec?

How come a device can't record a video at a specific resolution(ex:1280x270), but still be able to play any kind of video at this resolution(I mean 1280x270)?

**NOTE: These stuff are occuring on low res device and not on higher ones.**

**EDIT**

the video is recorded using media projection not camera.

Comment: "when I use these sizes on media recorder: 320x240 or 480x270 or 1280x270" -- perhaps the device does not support those resolutions. Stick with `CamcorderProfile` and supported profiles. "How come a device can't record a video at a specific resolution(ex:1280x270), but still be able to play any kind of video at this resolution(I mean 1280x270)?" -- a camera is not involved in video playback.

Comment: @CommonsWare  the video is recorded from mediaprojection not camera do same rules apply......and eventhough I used camcorder I still get these green lines...the green lines only go when I use square dimensions.

Comment: @CommonsWare what is your advice in this case?

Comment: "the video is recorded from mediaprojection not camera do same rules apply" -- this is not in your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry I edited the question. So why this is happening?

Comment: I have no idea. I have only ever used the media projection APIs to record the screen at the actual screen resolution, not at arbitrary other resolutions.

Comment: @CommonsWare I also used the device dimensions to record screen but I got green lines. I want to control the size of the recorded video so that I don't get large sizes because as you know videos tend to get large when dimensions are high.....But the other main question is why this doesn't occur when using media codec api?

Comment: @CommonsWare and is recording screen different from recording with camera? Same rules apply?